# using check box to delete multiple records using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

i am trying to delete some records form my database as along it obey the rule that make it to appear in the table, so am trying to make use of php and ajax to complete this action. Though i copied the code online to perform the action. 
But this is what i notice, anytime i select the records that i want to delete, it will just fade out the selected row but on refresh of the page the record will re-appear which meant am missing something which i don't know, here is the code\

**index.php**

```
    <?php
//include auth.php file on all secure pages
require("../db.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login");
exit(); }
?>
<?php require_once('header.php')?>  
 <?php
//index.php
$query = "SELECT * FROM consignment WHERE shipmentstatus='Pending'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>
<div class="container content">


   <?php
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
   {
   ?>
   <div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
        <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Consignment No</th>
        <th>Origin</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Pickup Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th >Action</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
   <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
   ?>
   <tbody>
     <tr id="<?php echo $row["consignmentno"]; ?>" >
       <td><?php echo $row["consignmentno"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["shipmentorigin"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["shipmentdestination"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["shipmentpickupdate"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["shipmentstatus"]; ?></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="customer_id[]" class="delete_customer" value="<?php echo $row["consignmentno"]; ?>" /></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   <?php
    }
   ?>
    </table>
   </div>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   <div align="center">
    <button type="button" name="btn_delete" id="btn_delete" class="btn btn-success">Delete</button>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#btn_delete').click(function(){

  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
  {
   var id = [];

   $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
    id[i] = $(this).val();
   });

   if(id.length === 0) //tell you if the array is empty
   {
    alert("Please Select atleast one checkbox");
   }
   else
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:'deleterecord.php',
     method:'POST',
     data:{id:id},
     success:function()
     {
      for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++)
      {
       $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
       $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
      }
     }

    });
   }

  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
 });

});
</script>

<?php require_once('footer.php')?>
```

And here is the delete page processor
**deleterecord.php**

```
<?php
require("../db.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login");
exit(); }
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 foreach($_POST["id"] as $id)
 {
  $query = "DELETE FROM consignment WHERE consignmentno = '".$id."'";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Set error logging to catch warnings and check what errors you get. It could be your db connection, or your query.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, parameterize that query. You also can do all the deletes with 1 query.

Comment: Attempts to check the values ​​that are being sent in the array id.You can do this by the consol of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

****HERE is tested full code****

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container content">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" border="1">  
        <thead>  
            <tr>
                <th>Consignment No</th>
                <th>Origin</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Pickup Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th >Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name='consignment_no[]' value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name='consignment_no[]' value="2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name='consignment_no[]' value="3" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" align="center"><button type="button" name="btn_delete" id="btn_delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Records</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</div>
</div>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btn_delete').click(function () {

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
        {
            var id = [];

            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
                id[i] = $(this).val();
            });


            if (id.length === 0) //tell you if the array is empty
            {
                alert("Please Select atleast one checkbox");
            } else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'deleterecord.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function ()
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
                        {
                         //   $('tr#' + id[i] + '').css('background-color', '#ccc');
                          //  $('tr#' + id[i] + '').fadeOut('slow');

                            $('tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').find('td').each(function () {

                                $(this).css('background-color', '#ccc');
                                $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                                // this = td element
                            });
                        }
                    }

                });
            }

        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });

 });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `$post` is invalid syntax and there is no index `'consignment_no'` being sent.

Comment: you should handle it using ajax ..can you send your javascript/jquery code ?

Comment: OP ***is*** using ajax...look at the code in the question

Comment: just modify this lines $("input:checkbox[name=consignment_no]:checked").each(function(){
   id.push($(this).val());
});

Comment: what problem would that solve? Sure the selector is more specific but if `$(':checkbox:checked')` doesn't return match being more specific won't help. Don't guess at what might be wrong in answers

Comment: @SagarRoy the answer you posted makes the jquery to alert that nothing was selected. kindly check

Comment: Will really be grateful to anyone who can help re-write the code to just work for my aim which is to make the checkbox delete the records that are been checked. Thanks

Comment: please see my last tested solution

Comment: just change this lines under ajax

Comment: still the same @SagarRoy Please help me out

Comment: @Sagar Roy what does it mean by`===`  in `if (id.length === 0)`

Comment: its checking if there any checkbox checked or not .

Answer (score 0):

May be there is some problem in id.
Try to use this in script

```
$.each($(':checkbox:checked'),function(){ 
id.push($(this).val()); 
});
```